# Build fail on DEMO project using Android suite

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to build a demo app of Ad Serving for App developers.
I download Android studio through http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html .

However, I got a lot error like

```
Error: (3,19) java: package android.app does not exist
Error: (4,18) java: package android.os does not exist
Error: (5,20) java: package android.view does not exist
Error: (6,25) java: package android.view.View does not exist
Error: (7,20) java: package android.view does not exist
Error: (8,22) java: package android.widget does not exist
.....
```

I use original code from http://openx.com/product/mobile-ad-serving-for-app-developers/ without doing any modifications.
I tried Android API 19 and 21 Platform through Project Structure but in vain.

It seems the solution is very simple.  However, I cannot solve it until now.